# How to prioritise the filtering in LINQ queries, preferably Lambda format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

My example query is:

```
db.Supplier.Where(r=>r.Category.Name=="Food" && r.SupplierType.Code=="ShortValue" && Model.Pattern.Contains(r.Value))))
```

I want to do this first:

```
db.Supplier.Where(r=>r.Category.Name=="Food" && r.SupplierType.Code=="ShortValue"
```

then apply, the following, to the result set:

```
 && Model.Pattern.Contains(r.Value)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I do not really understand the question , how does it effect the result if the .Container() is in the same query or after the first query?

Comment: Apologies. I need to apply the first query, which removes a lot of rubbish records with long r.Values. The first query should return about 5 records. I can then apply the "Contains" to just these 5 records with Values with a max length of 50 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is just the speed that you are worried about , I am guessing that you do not want to perform the `Contains()` on everything in the table , you just want to find all results that match the first 2 rules and then check them all if they Contain the right Value, in that case you can do:

```
var result = db.Supplier.Where(r=>r.Category.Name=="Food" && 
                               r.SupplierType.Code=="ShortValue").ToList();
result = result.Where(r=>Model.Pattern.Contains(r.Value));
```

by adding `.ToList()` this forces the query to return a result , then query the first result set.

or , you can let the .Net Framework figure out the best way to execute the query and do something like:

```
IQueryable<Suppliers> results = db.Supplier.Where( x  => x.Category.Name == "Food");
results = results.Where(x => x.SupplierType.Code == "ShortValue");
results = results.Where( x => Model.Pattern.Contains(x.Value);
```

see , when you use `Iqueryable<>` then .Net will delay execution and is supposd to prioritize the order and how the search is executed

The real difference is *What part do you want done in the DB and what part do you want done in memory?*  You can use Ienumerable and IQueryable in different ways to return different results , you can have all the fintering done in the db and only return the exact results that you want, or you can have part of the query done in the done and it returns a lot back to memory and then the second part of the filter executes.  Which one to choose really depends on your application, but most of the time bringing less into memory and letting the db to do the hardwork is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I anticipated that using ToList() would force the DB to do the first bit, which reduces the resultset to about 5 records. I can then do the second bit in memory. This is actually part of a SelectList() statement. Is it possible to combine both parts into one LINQ query?

Comment: I think reducing this to 1 line or 1 query in my opinion won't do anything but further confuses the reader , I think having it broken into 2 makes what you are doing a lot more apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = db.Supplier.Where(r=>r.Category.Name=="Food" && r.SupplierType.Code=="ShortValue");
result = result.Where(r=>Model.Pattern.Contains(r.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to have it in the same query. Also the first bit needs to execute first, so the "Contains" should only get applied to ResultSet1, not all the records.